# np.dot is giving a Value Error about shapes

Tags: numpy

```
a = np.arange(3*4*5*6).reshape((3,4,5,6))
print(np.dot(a, a))
```

This always gives an **ValueError: shapes (3,4,5,6) and (3,4,5,6) not aligned: 6 (dim 3) != 5 (dim 2)**

I don't understand what is wrong?

Thanks for your Help :)

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Study the `dot` docs more.  Practice with 2d arrays first.

Comment: Do you know how to do a matrix product by hand?

Comment: I have tried it with 2d arrays and the code works. I am trying to implement Cosine Similarity and I need to take dot product